# Error: A JNI error has occurred, in windows 10 IntelliJ JDK-11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, java-11

When i am trying to compile i get an error in intelliJ:

- Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
- mapl/Compile has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only re
  cognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I appear to be using the correct version of JDK(11) and i am using the same one as the rest of my class so i am confused as to why i am getting this error.

[image]

I have also checked my versions of Java and Javacc and it seems to be installed correctly so i am confused as to why i am getting this error

[image]

Any potential fixes i can try?

EDIT:
using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with the version on IntelliJ you are using?

Comment: yes of course i have done so

Comment: What language level is selected for project ("Project Structure | Project/Modules") and compiler ("Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler")?

Comment: 1) project language level is "11 - local variable syntax for lambda parameters"
2) Java compiler: Javac

Comment: Could you please post screenshot from "Settings / Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler"

Comment: @y.bedrov hi added screenshot in the question, please check. thank you